# CakePHP Ignoring Containable With Pagination?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many, containable

I want to have cakephp paginate data and still use `containable`, but for some reason it seems to ignore my pleas to `contain` anything and just gives me back the entire `Tenant` row.  In my `TenantsController` I have the following code:

```
$conditions = array('ManagersTenant.manager_id'=>$this->Auth->User('id'));
$this->Tenant->ManagersTenant->recursive = 1;
$this->set('tenants',$this->paginate($this->Tenant->ManagersTenant, $conditions, array(
        'recursive'=>1,
        'contain'=>array(
            'username'
            )
        )
    ));
```

I'm simply trying to retrieve a `Tenant` but display only the `username` (`Tenant` is just an alias for my `User` model).

What am I doing wrong here?  If it helps, cakephp is throwing an *Undefined Index: Group* notice at me under the `Group` column.  I believe my model relationships are find because I can make cake retrieve the right data using `find()`, it's just when I try to use pagination that it breaks.

Comment: What is `username`? A model? A field?

Comment: you should be more specific on what you're trying to acheive

Comment: Please see additional info above.  I want to retrieve a `Tenant` but only display certain fields (i.e. `username`) with pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use the model name as the key:

```
...'contain' => array('Tenant' => array('username'))
```

Secondly, using the Containable behaviour trumps recursive, so don't bother setting it.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I was forgetting the MVC model and trying to make the controller do what I should have been doing in the view.  Containable was working the whole time.  I just needed to remove the pagination elements from the view and I'm all set now.